# RecyclerView addOnItemTouchListener wrong item position after sort the recyclerview by date

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` that contains my data from newest to oldest. Before I sorting the data by date, this onclick `RecyclerView` doing really well. It will send some variable to another intent.
But after I sorting the `RecyclerView` by date, the `RecyclerView` sort well but the `addOnItemTouchListener` send the wrong data position which is data before the `RecyclerView` is sorted.

I mean `addOnItemTouchListener` send the position before `RecyclerView` is sorted.

```
     mRecycleView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), mRecycleView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                DaftarTugas tugas = listTugas.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PengumumanTugasDetail.class);
                Log.e("idtugasput","asd"+idTugasPut.get(position));

            daftarTugasRef.child(idTugasPut.get(position)).child("flag").setValue("o");

            intent.putExtra("flag", "tugas");
            intent.putExtra("namamatkultugas", namaMatkulPut.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("deskripsitugas", deskripsiTugasPut.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("judultugas", judulTugasPut.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("tanggalkumpul", tanggalKumpulPut.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("tanggaltugas", tanggalTugasPut.get(position));

            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

and this when list is added

```
DaftarTugas tugas = new DaftarTugas();
                                                    tugas = dataSnapshot3.getValue(DaftarTugas.class);
                                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
                                                    try {
                                                        Date mDate = sdf.parse(tugas.getTanggal_tugas());
                                                        long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                                                        tugas.setDate_milisecond(timeInMilliseconds);
                                                        //store this timeInMilliseconds in your POJO object
                                                        Log.e("timestamp2","asd"+tugas.getDate_milisecond());
                                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }



                                                    listTugas.add(tugas);

                                                    idTugasPut.add(idTugas);
                                                    namaMatkulPut.add(tugas.getNama_tugas());
                                                    deskripsiTugasPut.add(tugas.getDeskripsi_tugas());
                                                    tanggalKumpulPut.add(tugas.getTanggal_kumpul());
                                                    tanggalTugasPut.add(tugas.getTanggal_tugas());
                                                    judulTugasPut.add(tugas.getJudul_tugas());

Collections.sort(listTugas, new Comparator<DaftarTugas>() {
                                                            public int compare(DaftarTugas o1, DaftarTugas o2) {
                                                                if (o1.getDate_milisecond() > o2.getDate_milisecond()) {
                                                                    return -1;

                                                                } else if (o1.getDate_milisecond() < o2.getDate_milisecond()) {

                                                                    return 1;
                                                                } else {
                                                                    return 0;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

RecyclerTouchListenerClass

```
package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

myAdapter

```
package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Yehezkiel on 7/15/2018.
 */

public class myAdapterTugas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapterTugas.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<DaftarTugas> listTugas;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tanggal_tugas,judul_tugas,tanggal_kumpul,nama_matkul;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            nama_matkul = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.judul_p);
            judul_tugas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deskripsi_p);
            tanggal_tugas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tanggal_tugas);
        }
    }

    public myAdapterTugas(List<DaftarTugas> listTugas) {

        this.listTugas = listTugas;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.costume_row_tugas, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DaftarTugas tugas = listTugas.get(position);



        holder.nama_matkul.setText(tugas.getNama_tugas());
        holder.judul_tugas.setText(tugas.getJudul_tugas());
        holder.tanggal_tugas.setText(tugas.getTanggal_tugas());
        if(tugas.getFlag().equals("a")){
            holder.nama_matkul.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else{
            holder.nama_matkul.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listTugas.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: there is no such class in android SDK: `RecyclerTouchListener`

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Comment: i mean what i said: nobody knows anything about `RecyclerTouchListener` class

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code. please check

Comment: add all of your listeners inside custom `ViewHolder` and your problems will be solved by using `getAdapterPosition()` method

Comment: But I have to pass, the data from that listener activity sir.

Comment: again: add your listeners inside your custom `ViewHolder`

Comment: Im sorry sir, Im new in this. I have been updating my code again

Comment: so add your listener (or `GestureDetector`) in `public MyViewHolder(View view) {` constructor

Comment: Can u provide me with code sir?

Comment: its your job / homework - whats so hard in calling `View#setOn[Long]ClickListener()` method?

Comment: I just confused sir, not a lazy person

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from @pskink, I move the OnClickListener to the adapter like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final DaftarTugas tugas = listTugas.get(position);
        holder.nama_matkul.setText(tugas.getNama_tugas());
        holder.judul_tugas.setText(tugas.getJudul_tugas());
        holder.tanggal_tugas.setText(tugas.getTanggal_tugas());
        if(tugas.getFlag().equals("a")){
            holder.nama_matkul.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else if(tugas.getFlag().equals("o")){
            holder.nama_matkul.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PengumumanTugasDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("flag", "tugas");
            intent.putExtra("namamatkultugas", tugas.getNama_tugas());
            intent.putExtra("deskripsitugas", tugas.getDeskripsi_tugas());
            intent.putExtra("judultugas", tugas.getJudul_tugas());
            intent.putExtra("tanggalkumpul", tugas.getTanggal_kumpul());
            intent.putExtra("tanggaltugas", tugas.getTanggal_tugas());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```